# How do I monitor a specific task scheduler event to using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to monitor my specific task scheduler job with failure event code and alert me over email if that triggered, But I am not able to understand that how to create a code, can someone please help me with PowerShell code. Let me describe to you, what exactly I want to try -

1. Like I have a specific task with the name of Upload.
2. I want to capture the failure event in the log file
3. Send an email if a failure event triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, attached task to this event... from the event viewer.

In the event viewer, you can explorer the following path:

> Event Viewer (Local) / Applications and Services Logs / Microsoft /
> Windows / TaskScheduler / Operational

For each task, events there should generated with event ids , you just need to attach the a notification task that suiting your requirement.

Comment: @Mohmood, But that will show for every task if any failed and I want to capture only specific task.

Comment: That's right, however suppose you are running the task at 12:00, and it should be completed in 5 min, you can schedule another task to read the event log at 12:05 and with the help of if statement in case of failure task you can get notification.

Comment: Could you provide an example code for the same so I can get an idea and changes with my requirements?